# Percona xtrabackup bypass xbcloud locally

Tags: backup, restore, percona, xtrabackup, xbcloud

I normally sync to my storage box which is running minio via `xtrabackup` and `xbcloud put` similar to https://docs.percona.com/percona-xtrabackup/8.0/xbcloud-minio.html. Then in order to restore a backup I use this command:

```
xbcloud get s3://database/202311112041-full_backup --s3-endpoint='http://storage.domain.com:9000' --s3-access-key='minioadmin' --s3-secret-key='#####' --parallel=10 | xbstream -x -C restore --parallel=8
```

However, I want to restore the backup on the local minio server; So I want to access the backup but not have it go through xbcloud/s3 since I am executing the commands locally and just want to use xbstream to restore it.

Is this possible? What command would I run assuming `s3://database/202311112041-full_backup` correlates to `/mnt/data/database/202311112041-full_backup`